# Advice on migrating RDS MySQL databases from one AWS account to another

Tags: mysql, backup, amazon-web-services, backup-restoration, rds

I am currently planning a migration of AWS resources from one account to another. This includes several MySQL RDS instances.

After some research it looks like a "dump and load" strategy is needed. My goal was to dump everything that was part of the server; users, databases, grants, any triggers, events, what have you.

I did the backup using the following command:

```
$ mysqldump -h migration-test-src1.cmgwbovklkqq.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -u mysql_admin -ppswd --hex-blob --routines --triggers --events --all-databases > migration-test-src1.dump
```

which worked fine, but I get the following error when trying to restore to the destination RDS instance:

```
$ mysql -h migration-test-dest1.cmgwbovklkqq.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -u mysql_admin -ppswd < migration-test-src1.dump
ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 38: Access denied for user 'mysql_admin'@'%' to database 'mysql'
```

I'm not quite sure why the restore isn't working. I'm not a DBA, so I was hoping I might find someone here that is willing to help.

Is there something I can do to get the file restored? Is the strategy I am using to do that back and restore flawed?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Well, your log message indicates that your mysql_admin user's access was denied to the mysql table. Fix that problem and try again.

Comment: Maybe this is related to ie being an RDS instance and not a MySQL server I fully control.

`mysql> SHOW GRANTS for 'mysql_admin'@'localhost';
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user       'mysql_admin' on host 'localhost'
mysql> select User from mysql.user;
+-------------+
| User        |
+-------------+
| mysql_admin |
| rdsadmin    |
+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mysql_admin'@'localhost';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mysql_admin'@'%' (using password: YES)`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know how to get new lines into a comment,

Comment: Edit your answer to include the new information.

Comment: You can't `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` in RDS because you don't *have* all privileges.  You have to grant privs explicitly by name.  Also, `@'localhost'` is meaningless in RDS because you can't connect from localhost (the RDS machine itself).  Use `@'%'` or an appropriate IP address or IP wildcard instead.  Finally, the MySQL schema (which is where the error on line 38 claims to be) is subject to additional restrictions on RDS and a full mysqldump is unlikely to work.